# How to restrict Azure AD App to My application only

Tags: azure, oauth, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I have registered an application in Azure AD portal for oauth and working fine with my web application www.test.com.I have a concern that , the token generated by the client id and secret can be used in another application say www.otherapp.com.Is there any way to restrict that the app can only be used by www.test.com.

Comment: As far as I know, only applications registered in the tenant can be restricted to a specific set of users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is currently no way to limit the Azure AD App to your application. If you are concerned that other users in the tenant will use the Azure AD app that you have registered, you can set the application to only specific users. You can Refer to this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-restrict-your-app-to-a-set-of-users#update-the-app-to-enable-user-assignment).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I was wondering whether any restrictions can be done with redirect uri.

Comment: @David Redirect url has no such restriction. But as long as you do not configure `www.otherapp.com` as the redirect url, your Azure ad app will not have any connection with `www.otherapp.com`.

Comment: @David Yes, as allen said, there is no such restriction on redirect URLs.